# groc javascript documentor - arguments to document all subdirectories

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation, glob, groc

Using the [node.js npm](http://nevir.github.com/groc/) package what is the command (osx bash $ groc) to create documentation for files in `path/to/thisDirectory` and all subdirectories?

```
$ cd path/to/thisDirectory
$ groc App/scripts/**/*.js
```

The above only processes files one level deeper than `/scripts/` and none above or below ... which makes sense!

I probably just need to know the syntax for getting subdirectories. I couldn't find info anywhere else.

Globbing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the groc manual, it says you should quote the globbed path to let groc do the expansion:

```
$ groc "App/scripts/**/*.js"
```

Comment: using: `$ groc "App/scripts/*"` is working as needed; recursing into subdirectories. As you say quoting with "" was the important point as passing the quoted path means bash ignores the path and so lets groc handle the expansion of the path. Thanks

Comment: ... groc just ignores files it doesn't recognise and proceeds to process the next file / sub-dir in the expanded path.